# How to ccreate Windows10 GUI docker image

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Is it possible to create a docker image for Windows 10 with GUI support? I want to run the browser and some stand-alone app on windows GUI. So far I have found the same for CentOS for not for windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not sure if windows has allowed to use its kernel for free images as its the revenue generating platform for them.
2. Rancher group works on making GUI based docker images you can refer there site for such information link : https://rancher.com/
3. Rancher has also few images of windows on hub.docker.com for demonstration purpose which you can checkout freely. The only concern is they are large in size around 2.5 Gigs
4. This may not be relevant but ios images are already available if you want to try you can refer the link :  https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX